# Understanding Dijkstra's notation $f.x.y$

Tags: terminology, history

I recently discovered that I have a fondness for the work of Dijkstra. I am currently reading random EWDs, and stumbled across one [with some notation that I couldn't quite grasp](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd10xx/EWD1014.PDF).

Dijkstra states that $[ x < y \implies f.x.y < f.y.x]$

OK, so. This isn't a list comprehension, right? Why the brackets?

Also, how could this be read aloud? What does $\implies$ mean?

And finally, what does $f.x.y$ and $f.y.x$ mean?

And how could this statement be written more conventionally? And does Dijkstra's notation derive from anything, or is it entirely his own invention?

Answer (score 8):

I think this would read as follows in modern notation (although  field-local variations are possible):

$$\forall x y. x < y \Rightarrow f(x,y) < f(y,x).$$

Read aloud: *for all x and y, x is less than y implies that f of x and y 
is less than f of y and x*.

If you read the first sentence of the linked document, it says that square brackets represent universal quantification over $x$ and $y$. The second states that $f$ is a function. `=>` is ASCII art for $\Rightarrow$ (logical implication).

The main problem here is missing context (and detective skills). This article refers to [EWD878](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD878.PDF). Perhaps looking there would have helped. Indeed, looking at that article, you see notation slightly closer to what is used today (at least, by Haskell programmers: `f.x.y` becomes `f\ x\ y`).